# Compress sequence in clojure

Tags: clojure, sequence

I'm trying to solve http://www.4clojure.com/problem/30 and end-up with following code:

`(fn [a] reduce #(if (= (last %1) %2) %1 (concat %1 (seq %2))) (empty a) (seq a))`

The idea is to append symbols one-by-one if they don't equal to the last symbol of the current result string. But for some reason that I don't see it returns the same sequence as its input.

`>((fn [a] reduce #(if (= (last %1) %2) %1 (concat %1 (seq %2))) (empty a) (seq a)) "Leeeeroy") 
(\L \e \e \e \e \r \o \y)`

I tried to evaluate different sub-expressions, like 
`(= (first (seq "Lee")) (last (seq "L")))`
and they seem to be correct. Could someone point out what is the issue with this function?

Comment: I think you've missed some braces so your function returns (seq a) and not (reduce ...)

Comment: I just checked my solution from when i did this and it's almost identical! you can replace `(empty a)` with `'()` as the solutions all work with lists at the end, and as pointed out elsewhere, whatever you pass to your reduce will be sequenced automatically, so replace `(seq a)` with just `a`. although, i would call it `xs` to show you're using as a sequence. As has been pointed out too, you didn't wrap reduce in brackets.

Comment: @MarkFisher No need for the quote on `()`, Mark.

Comment: @Thumbnail : indeed, however i seem to have a habit of always quoting lists even when they are empty so I can visually scan it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your function is incorrect in many fronts. When you define an anonymous function, I guess you wanted to place a `reduce` form, but you actually ended up sequentially placing a function `reduce`, then another anonymous function `#(if ...), etc.

When you fixed this, you'll see some new errors of your code and hope you can work on that afterwards. :)

Answer (score 1):

- You did not wrap your reduce form in `( ... )`, so got the value of
  the last form, `(seq a)`. By the way, the `seq` call is redundant.
- Your use of `seq` in `(concat %1 (seq %2))` is wrong. `seq` sequences
  a collection; it does not make a sequence out of an element.
- You want an empty sequence as an initial value for the `reduce`.
  There are simpler ways to express this than `(empty a)`.

If you put these faults right, it works. But you'll find it slows to a crawl on a long sequence. The reason is that `last` runs right through the accumulating solution for every element. Have a look at other solutions to see how to avoid this.

There is a fairly neat solution employing `partition-all`, `remove` or `filter`, and `map`.